# horizontal and vertical join count in r dataframe

Tags: r

having a dataframe with sales per customer and months.

```
df <-
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              date = c("jan","jan","jan","jan",
                       "jan","jan","jan","feb","feb","feb","feb","feb",
                       "feb","feb"),
          customer = c("john","john","john","Mary",
                       "Mary","Mary","Mary","Robert","Robert","Mary",
                       "john","john","Robert","Robert"),
           product = c("a","b","d","a","b","c",
                       "d","a","b","c","a","c","c","d")

   date customer product
1   jan     john       a
2   jan     john       b
3   jan     john       d
4   jan     Mary       a
5   jan     Mary       b
6   jan     Mary       c
7   jan     Mary       d
8   feb   Robert       a
9   feb   Robert       b
10  feb     Mary       c
11  feb     john       a
12  feb     john       c
13  feb   Robert       c
14  feb   Robert       d
```

I need to summarize how many times the same customer is present across months and products.

Expected result:

```
 date          a       b       c       d    same cust
  jan          2       2       1       2         0
  feb          2       1       2       0         1
  same cust    1       0       1       0
```

Comment: can you explain why  there is a `1`for `feb`  in the last column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    date = c("jan","jan","jan","jan",
             "jan","jan","jan","feb","feb","feb","feb","feb",
             "feb","feb"),
    customer = c("john","john","john","Mary",
                 "Mary","Mary","Mary","Robert","Robert","Mary",
                 "john","john","Robert","Robert"),
    product = c("a","b","d","a","b","c",
                "d","a","b","c","a","c","c","d"))

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(date,names_from=product,values_from=customer,values_fn=length)%>%
  bind_cols(SCust = table(df$customer, df$date) %>% apply(2, \(x) sum(x>=2))) %>% 
  bind_rows(c(tibble(date="SCust"),
            table(df$customer, df$product) %>% apply(2, \(x) sum(x>=2))))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   date      a     b     d     c SCust
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 jan       2     2     2     1     2
#> 2 feb       2     1     1     3     2
#> 3 SCust     1     0     0     1    NA
```

Comment: Error: unexpected input in:
"  tidyr::pivot_wider(date,names_from=product,values_from=customer,values_fn=length) %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols(SCust = table(df$customer, df$date) %>% apply(2, \"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Forge. I have just checked on my computer and I get absolutely no error! It seems that you are not using the latest version of R. Thus, if you replace `\(x) sum(x>=2)` by `function(x) sum(x>=2)`, I guess it will work on your old R version.

Comment: @Forge: the syntax `\(x)` is very recent (from `R-4.1.0` onward).

Comment: ah, sorry my bad. I have version 4.0

Comment: But my solution will work on your R version, if you do the replacement I have suggested to you. Good luck, @Forge!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the marginals, but for the main table

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(
  df,
  date~product,
  function(x){length(unique(x))},
  value.var="customer"
)

  date a b c d
1  feb 2 1 3 1
2  jan 2 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = product, values_from = customer, values_fn = n_distinct) %>% 
 bind_rows(
  df %>% 
    count(product, customer) %>%
    group_by(product) %>% 
    summarise(n=sum(n-1), 
              date = "all") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = product,values_from=n ))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  date      a     b     d     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 jan       2     2     2     1
2 feb       2     1     1     3
3 all       1     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  date = c("jan","jan","jan","jan", "jan","jan","jan","feb","feb","feb","feb","feb","feb","feb"),
  customer = c("john","john","john","Mary", "Mary","Mary","Mary","Robert","Robert","Mary","john","john","Robert","Robert"),
  product = c("a","b","d","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","a","c","c","d")
)
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
setorder(dt, product)

rbindlist(list(
  dcast(dt[, .(value = .N), by = .(date, product)], date ~ product),
  transpose(dt[, .(same_cust_row = .N - length(unique(customer))), by = .(product)], make.names = "product", keep.names = "date")
))

#             date a b c d
# 1:           feb 2 1 3 1
# 2:           jan 2 2 1 2
# 3: same_cust_row 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: seems ok but lacks right side column

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want in the right column, besides sometimes answers are meant to give someone a direction, not per se to get the job completely done for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the "detail" data, or just the summary ("same cust") data?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
# by month / same customer bought in both months
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = product, values_from = date, values_fn = length) %>%
            select(-customer) %>%
            map( ~ sum(.x==2))

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 0

$d
[1] 0

$c
[1] 1


# by month / same customer bought all (4) products
z <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = product, values_fn = length) %>%
            select(-customer) %>%
            map( ~ sum(.x==4))

$jan
[1] NA

$feb
[1] 1
```

Comment: just the summary

Comment: Well, if I interpreted what you want, the above code gets it really quickly.  If you want customers that bought multiple products in the period (not all 4) simply adjust the clause from sum(.x==4) to sum(.x>=2)